# SVN relocate repository for working copy

Tags: svn, svn-repository, svn-switch

Here is **svn info** of the working copy.

```
URL: svn://192.168.1.10/svn/MyRepos
Repository Root: svn://192.168.1.10
```

And this is what I expect

```
URL: svn://192.168.1.10/MyRepos
Repository Root: svn://192.168.1.10/MyRepos
```

What should I do with it? Thanks in advance. ^_^

Comment: Why does the IP address are different between  URL and Rep. Root?

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva Sorry, my mistake. They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tortoise SVN 1.7+ you can right click on the folder and than press "Switch". There you can choose the new path of your source.
Also make you sure you have all privileges to browse that path.

Comment: Thank you for your post. But there is no GUI environment around, and the SVN version is 1.6.18. My situation is that both the repository root and the URL relative path are changed, so it seems neither _svn switch_ or _svn switch --relocate_ worked here.